# Cannot get right resolution with Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I am using the latest propriety Nvidia driver on 15.10. I currently have two screens attached to my GTX960. My problem is that one of them is connected through a VGA to DVI adapter and apparently the screen isn't managing to communicate its resolution options properly through this adapter. The result of this is that that monitor is running at a below average resolution and neither the Nvidia control centre thing nor Ubuntu's display settings page is giving me the option of the right resolution. How can I force the correct resolution on that display without having to resort to something that will be lost after a reboot or that will most likely cause trouble with future updates?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is recommended to use the NVIDIA drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories.
But when there are problems with these drivers, you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers.
This often leads to properly working graphics - especially on very new hardware such as your GTX 960.

NVIDIA lately released the final long-lived branch drivers version 361.
These drivers already are available in the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Remove the currently installed drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest official stable drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Ok,  I'll give this a try but I think this is a fundamental problem where the systen is not able to read the edid and instead of the driver asking for the proper resolution, it guesses a useless one.